# How to show all the entries even some value in the table not exact and put zero inplace of total #SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

im creating a small software in vb.net that need some sql query expression so i dont need to store the balance of each customer and i will explain it exactly as below;

this is my current query i use to show a list of customers that owes money to the company;

```
Select custs.*, Sum(dem.amnt) As balance
FROM custs
INNER JOIN dem
On custs.name = dem.c_name 
where dem.paid='0'
GROUP BY custs.name
```

the query make select from customers table and join transaction table from table named (DEM)

the query lists only customers with unpaid debts checking paid column "paid" if 0 or 1 and adds a column of total debt of each customer

i want to show all the entries even the customer dont have any debt with 0 balance

Comment: Do you want to show all customers regardless of debt?  Why not just remove the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: this is the customer table **im not using bal column**  [link](http://imgur.com/JTjPh61) and here transaction table where jhon transactions marked as paid [link](http://imgur.com/EqqFP0Q)  and finally the query result , here jhon has unpaid transaction if i set it to paid jhon wil not show up i want to show it with zero balance [link](http://imgur.com/w8LwMQ0)

Comment: Your being very unclear.

Comment: check again my comment

Comment: Show us a minimal sample of data for both the `custs` and `dem` tables.

Comment: i got my answer from @Dylan Su; Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select custs.*, Sum(dem.amnt * (1 - dem.paid)) As balance
FROM custs
LEFT JOIN dem
On custs.name = dem.c_name 
GROUP BY custs.name
```

Comment: your query acted as mine , one second i will upload some screenshots

Comment: @yoss Updated. Try again.

Comment: still not working, please check my comment under the original post with screenshots

Comment: @yoss Update again. pls try

Comment: the code is better, but it gives zero when all of the transaction is paid and if there is one unpaid transaction the query will sum up all of the transactions paid and unpaid together, thanks

Comment: @yoss Update. try again. I am almost confused.